# Quantum duality: variable is null and undefined at the same time?

Tags: javascript, comparison

Consider following JavaScript code (tested in Firefox):

```
function f(a) {

  if (a == undefined) {
    alert('undefined');
  }

  if (a == null) {
    alert('null');
  }
}

f();
```

Both alerts are shown, suggesting that both statements are true.

Could you provide a reasonable explanation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`==` is a "soft" equality operator.
It uses type coercion to compare two equivalent objects as equal.

All of the following are true:

```
42 == "42"
0 == false
0 == ""
[] == ""
{} == "[object Object]"
'/(?:)/' == new RegExp
```

Instead, you should use the  `===` operator, which checks for strict equality.

Comment: It gets better: `[[[[[[[[[[2]]]]]]]]]] == 2`

Comment: +1 didn't know an RE and its string equivalent are true: `'/(?:)/' == /(?:)/` -> true!!

Comment: Even `'/x/' == /x/` -> true, `'/x/' == /y/` -> false !